# Convert inputs ANN to time series for forecasting

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I want to ask about artificial neural networks, ANN. Do I need to convert inputs of ANN to time series if I want to do forecast ? Thank you in advance for answering my question.

Comment: [Reading material](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2314728817300144). If the data is not a time series what does the word *forecast* mean? Try some other wording, e.g., extrapolation.